# Restoring table structure with mysqlfrm

Tags: mysql, restore

I'm trying to restore an old MySQL database and its tables by using the .frm and .ibd files.

First I tried restoring the structure by using the following command I found in another post:

```
mysqlfrm.exe --server=root:password@localhost "C:/location_of_file/file.frm" --port=3307
```

When I execute the command it says the following: "ERROR: Cannot find location of mysql_system_tables.sql."

Where is this file stored? Or do I have to execute this command in a specific location?

Comment: Why are you using this method? Can you start an older version of mysql and take a dump of these tables (this would be cleaner)?. There is https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/5.6/scripts/mysql_system_tables.sql, however its largely dependent on the version you are restoring so select the right version.

Comment: What version of MySQL?  Did you save `ibdata1`?